# iOSでPDFファイルをAdobe Acrobat Readerに渡す方法

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

Adobe Acrobat Readerの画面にはなるのですが、指定したPDFが表示されません。どうしたらいいでしょうか？

```
-(void)hoge:(UIButton*)button{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"title1"fType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"com.adobe.Adobe-Reader://%@", path]];

    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    [application openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"Opened url");
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: adobe acrobat readerの画面にはなるのですが、指定したpdfが表示されません。どうしたらいいでしょうか？

Comment: URLスキーマは設定されていてもファイルを指定するような仕組みにはなっていないように見えます。現在はOpen InやUser Activityなどファイル共有の仕組みがちゃんと用意されていますので、URLスキーマよりもそちらを使った方が簡単だと思います。